# Stop setInterval when div has display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using on my site setInterval function to load new content to one div every 20 seconds. It's working fine (at least seems like, maybe there is better option to do this?).

The problem is I want to use responsive design and on small screens this div will have display:none property, however JS function will still working and 'eat' data.

Is there any possibility that this code can't run when div has display:none attribute?

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#test').load("test.php");
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Why don't you put an `if` check inside the function for that? Or set the interval only if div does not have display none? You can do this by measuring the div's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a check if the `div` is visible or not inside the `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function() {
    if($('#test').is(':visible')) //if visible then load
          $('#test').load("test.php");
}, 20000);
```

You can also check specifically for `display` property

```
    setInterval(function() {
        if($('#test').css('display') != 'none') //if display not none then load
              $('#test').load("test.php");
    }, 20000);
```

Comment: @xyz124 Sometimes happens :)

Comment: I'd suggest assigining the interval to a variable and clearing it if the div is hidden as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if an attribute is visible using this code:

```
$(element).is(":visible");
```

so you can write:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if($('#test').is(":visible"){    
        $('#test').load("test.php");
    }
}, 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check is `#test` displayed:

```
var test = $('#test');
if(test.css("display")!="none")
    test.load("test.php");
```